# Can SE focus on issues that the community actually cares about?

Tags: discussion, community, community-standards

Recently I've noticed that since the whole Monica controversy SE has been implementing some interesting updates to the system. Here's just a few of them: <sub>*(leaving out the Monica situation for now)*</sub>

- The Overflow, which is their latest blog-newsletter-informational-article? It was released with controversial response, especially the automatic opt-in which is even suspected to be [non](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334228/)-[GDPR](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390009/) [compliant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334354/).
- [Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/12/research-update-a-b-testing-the-new-question-form/). [Lots](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/) [and](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/08/ben-popper-is-the-worst-coder-in-the-world-quantum-edition/) [lots](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/07/using-machine-learning-to-create-reviews-of-apis-from-stack-overflow-comments/) [of](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/06/lets-get-graphic-a-few-ways-to-draw-on-the-web/) [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/04/a-technical-deep-dive-into-our-ms-teams-integration/) [posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/04/microsoft-teams-integration-announcement/). I see a new post on the [Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog) almost every day now, which is very unusual, since in the past it seems like there would be a post once or twice a week.
- An [unexpected revival](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/15/the-stack-overflow-podcast-is-back/) of the [Stack Overflow Podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast) after a year and a half of inactivity.
- Multiple new integrations, including a [MS Teams integration](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/04/microsoft-teams-integration-announcement/) and [GitHub authentication](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/11/announcing-support-for-github-authentication-in-stack-overflow/).
- A controversial new so-called ["reputation inflation"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/), which [remains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338143) [controversial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/).

What I want to point out above is something alarming. The majority of decisions above were made with *no* community feedback before release, and some of the decisions directly contradict what the community desired (like the rep inflation decision).

I believe there are other, more pertinent, issues that the team needs to focus on. As a regular user, I don't care about any of these changes and there are other issues that need to be tackled first, namely the situation that is [well summed up here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965).

I also want to add [a point I made in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338156/can-se-focus-on-issues-that-the-community-actually-cares-about#comment1125775_338156):

> What bothers me... is that these features were requested, in some cases, years ago, and they are all being handled during one of the largest controversies in SE history. Seems like a massive coincidence if I've ever seen one.

For the first time in the past month, I feel helpless. What can we do?

Comment: My prediction: Microsoft is probably going to acquire SE or at the very least is interested.

Comment: At this point, I'm not even sure whether they are throwing out this change (which is not even "controversial", but clearly against the will of the community) as some sort of smoke screen, in the hope that the possibly illegal relicensing and the public defamation of a volunteer gets buried under a discussion about "some useless internet points". No matter whether you apply [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) or not: This is all just a huge, huge mess.

Comment: @connectyourcharger their acquisition of GitHub went quite well. If it's like that then I'm all for it.

Comment: We want to be heard, but say little to nothing of value. We want SE to change, while pointing in all directions. We, as a wall of noise, are constantly steering the discourse around outrage, entitlement, and full-on spoiled behavior. Everything SE does is wrong, we will not like it. That's the state of Meta SE. How is that valuable?

Comment: @Lyd '*We want to be heard, but say little to nothing of value.*' - Speak for yourself. So many suggestions have been made unless your saying that none of them have any value. '*We want SE to change, while pointing in all directions.*' - Nope. It's a common theme. We want more communication and transparency. '*We, as a wall of noise, are constantly steering the discourse around outrage, entitlement, and full-on spoiled behavior.*' - After being accused of being unwelcoming, after the number of failures that have happened recently, do you expect people not to be annoyed?

Comment: To be more direct about what Lyd is getting at: your question reads a lot like "I only care about one specific thing and everything else is dumb and nobody cares." You're wrong. A lot of people cared that the podcast was originally canceled, and wanted it to keep going - we brought it back. A lot of Teams clients wanted MS Teams integration. A lot of people [wanted GitHub integration](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309883/add-github-as-a-registration-login-option). It's ok if you don't want those things, but it's inaccurate to say the community as a whole doesn't care about them.

Comment: @animuson What bothers me more is that these features were requested, in some cases, *years* ago, and they are all being handled during one of the largest controversies in SE history. Seems like a massive coincidence if I've ever seen one.

Comment: Why does it matter how long ago they were requested? That's nothing new. There are *tons* of feature requests out there that took years to get implemented. I'd probably even guess *most* of them follow that pattern.

Comment: @animuson I mean, you have to see the pattern with the Teams integration and the GitHub authentication, no? Even if you look at it without the tin-foil hat, you'd see the coincidence. Compared to the myriad of other suggestions that people have made, the GH auth seems extremely minor.

Comment: @animuson Paired with the lack of community team response to any concerns on Meta and the fact that all of these happened in a month, I'd say this isn't your everyday common occurence.

Comment: @Lyd It's not clear what the point of this comment is (and in that regard, I agree to Script47). But if you think that SE has recently made *any* "right" decision, I'd be curious to hear which one this should be. At animuson: These are rather technical features. I'm sure that some people appreciate them. But they are shadowed by more important feature requests that have been ignored, and more importantly, by the series of decisions that did harm the community. Compared to that, something like the podcast is... well, cute, but irrelevant.

Comment: @Script47 You might be interested in researching apophenia.

Comment: @animuson maybe I have/am headed towards apophenia, but, I could just flip that around on you and say you're saying what you're saying because you're an employee therefore you'll of course be biased (ironic, right?).

Comment: @Script47 Perhaps, but it could also be because I'm aware of timelines and how long it takes for something to get from "idea" to "implementation" in our developer queues, and know that some of these things were already planned and scheduled long before any of these issues popped up. It's not as if someone a few weeks ago just popped in and said "hey, we're gonna do this feature now." I also happen to know that there's at least one feature that was postponed because of all that's been happening, despite also being planned beforehand.

Comment: @animuson Reminder - this is from the view of an average users. Diamond moderators are the 0.01% and most of us have no idea what goes on in the lab where all the hamsters run in their wheels all day. You have to understand where I come from, take off your moderator hat for a minute, and see how I can see this as a massive coincidence.

Comment: @animuson right and at that point, I'd submit to that fact that I don't have the big picture so I couldn't argue further. But take a look back at what I mentioned, I simply stated that you've definitely got to see a connection between the Teams integration and GitHub auth from a normal users perspective.

Comment: @Script47 hm I thought Microsoft started er... disrupting Nokia only after buying it, not before

Comment: @gnat I guess SE is trying to make themselves more presentable/profitable to squeeze more money before the deal?

Comment: @Script47 Why world Microsoft's lawyers ok a deal to buy a site with such a sketchy IP situation?

Comment: They can (at least I don't see a reason why not) but probably won't (or only to a small extent) judging by the past (say the last year).

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica didn’t stop Google from buying Youtube with all their copyright infringement.

Answer (score 25):

ok, so we keep praying and hoping that SE will listen to the community.  When do we all realize that SE is now broken beyond repair.  The company could care less about you, your opinion and what the community wants.  You are replaceable in their eyes.  All one has to do is read the posts on Meta to get a very clear picture how SE feels about the community.  3 people have utterly destroyed what was left of SE's reputation with the community and they are completely fine with it. Doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result is the definition of insanity....  until there is a change in leadership at SE there will be no resolution for the community.

We are a shadow without a light....walking through these endless nights.....

Comment: *until there is a change in leadership at SO* ...is that irony? the new CEO's seat hasn't even warmed up yet

Comment: [Some consider](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1183727708376838145) SO to be lacking clear leadership at all, so if the new CEO wanted to step out of the shadows and actually address any of this mess, then that would indeed be a change.  So far he seems content to ignore it.

Comment: Bingo.  Users are a resource.  If a bunch of users are upset, but we don't need them to have a viable site, we're fine.  I never got a whiff of this attitude before, but it's sure here now, as the powers that be try to move past their screwup.  I think it's a mistake.   The community is probably a big part of the success of and loyalty to the platform.

Comment: Is this answer a "No" to the question?

Comment: The answer is that we need to stop asking this question as the answer is all over SE.  The community no longer matters to SE.

Answer (score 4):

Some people still have so much illusions about SE.

You have to realize, that SE is a company. You know, the company, which wants to make money to survive.

So, most of decisions were made with this thing in mind. If a decision goes hand in hand with a community wants - great; if not, well...

So, regarding to your question: the company, probable, cares about the community, but tasks are prioritized by a company needs.

Comment: There is surely also a long-term financial aspect about having a happy, healthy community relation. Maybe they just misunderstand this partly. I'm on the fence between they are underestimating the importance of the community versus there is just a conflict of interest between them and the community.

Comment: Illusion or delusion?

Comment: @Script47 nice point)

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange seems to be focusing most of their effort on doing things that increase the number of people visiting the site... which in turn leads to increases in ad revenue. At the end of the day we need to keep reminding ourselves that they are not running the network for altruistic purposes but remain a for-profit enterprise.

While the social issues are a major concern for the more engaged members of the community, a lot of are also "low ad revenue" users due to our reputation or using various ad blockers. Practically speaking MSE is unlikely to be really be around that much longer since it's not exactly a high value site and might actually be more of a negative from a corporate standpoint.

Comment: And yet, after this change, they expect the people to continue answering for altruistic purposes while getting less benefit than those asking the questions!

Comment: Could be an experiment how much you can form your community. Danger is that people just might leave the platform at some point. They probably think they can reverse any time or do the stuff that the community wants anytime later without negative financial implications. I'm not sure. Sounds like a bet to me. Could go right, could go wrong.