# Does the recent question reputation change aim to fulfill moderation needs left by resigning moderators?

Tags: discussion, reputation, moderator-tools

The recent question rep reward change must have bumped several users to 10k or 'mod user'. Considering that last month there were so many moderators resigning or halting activity, possibly leaving the queue of flags unresolved, was this move by Stack Exchange aimed to get more users with moderation privileges to handle these flags? Is it even effective?

Comment: Sometimes, after a moment of unpleasant violence, the saloon owner offers a round of free drinks to subdue the uneasiness of the patrons.

Comment: To me it seems that this move serves the purpose of increasing the activity, i.e. to increase the number of question (and thus answers), and thus to have more people see the ads.

Comment: This question can easily be authoritatively answered by the employees involved.

Comment: Nah it's just yet another bad attempt to draw attention away from the elephant in the room. - "Umm... there's an elephant in this porcelain store." (In the background, sounds of porcelain breaking everywhere)  - "Of course not. May I interest you in this lovely vase?" (In the background, one of the walls fall down) - "Umm, it's a nice vase but who is going to clean up all this broken glass? Aren't those people running out through that hole in the wall your volunteer cleaners?"  - "Of course not. May I interest you in a vote score display experiment? New wording for close reasons?"

Comment: The expression you are looking for is: "[Bull in a China Shop](https://youtu.be/Xzw2iBmRsjs)", the expression "[Elephant in the Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant_in_the_room)" means something completely different and has nothing to do with porcelain.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's a comment by @animuson [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338156/can-se-focus-on-issues-that-the-community-actually-cares-about#comment1125787_338156):

> I'm aware of timelines and how long it takes for something to get from "idea" to "implementation" in our developer queues, and know that some of these things were already planned and scheduled long before any of these issues popped up. It's not as if someone a few weeks ago just popped in and said "hey, we're gonna do this feature now." I also happen to know that there's at least one feature that was postponed because of all that's been happening, despite also being planned beforehand.

This seems to imply (but I could interpret it the wrong way) that the reputation change was already in the works before the mass resignation of moderators following Monica's firing, so it's not an attempt to increase the moderation capability of the entire community.

Also, FYI, 10k/20k reputation doesn't give you much in terms of the review queue. VLQ and NAA flags end up in the Low Quality Posts review (accessible at 2k) and close flags in the Close Votes review queue (accessible at 3k). You need to be a ♦ moderator to handle comment flags and custom post flags; no amount of reputation will help there. It's an interesting theory nevertheless :)

Answer (score 15):

Fact is: that systematic "going back" and recounting reputations for all users was a *complex* project.

And from all that I have seen so far: it went pretty smooth. Some initial glitches here or there, for example regarding the *achievements* notification. But badge counters, daily limits, looking all good it seems. But overall: excellent technical execution.

My conclusion: they worked on that for quite some time, otherwise the transition would have been **much** more painful.

Thus it seems very unlikely that somewhen in October someone thought "OMG, we are losing more and more moderators, what can we do?" and some other person going "Hm, we could value up questions, so we get a bunch more 10K users, and they will cover that."

Very much doubt it. Almost on the "SE Inc. is run by reptile aliens" kinda "I doubt it" level.

My personal two cent: I don't care about the +3K I got on stackoverflow. Here on MSE, the +700 I saw ... about match what was "deducted" earlier this month, when the "Coc Updates FAQ version 1" question was deleted. Sure, those +700 pushed me over 10K yesterday, but honestly: the only gain I see from that is: I can now look at deleted content. Which is surely a truly valuable **privilege** these days.

Answer (score 8):

This is probably a case of [mixed motives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_motive_discrimination): there's not simply one reason for making the change.

1. The [official reason](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) is:

   > In short, **you need to be an expert question asker to ensure you’re going to get the best answer**. That takes skill and experience, it’s valuable, and **it’s something we want to celebrate**.

   It seems reasonable to believe this is a genuine motive by StackExchange for the change.

   And as [Em C](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338360/does-the-recent-question-reputation-change-aim-to-fulfill-moderation-needs-left#comment1126886_338360) links in the comments:

   > **The main reason for the change was to correct what we believe was a mistake** to change the reputation payout in the first place. -- [Jon Ericson](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13506) ♦
2. It's implausible that it's a merely a coincidence that the paper May, Wachs, and Hannák (2019) came out shortly before the change, and analyzed the effects of the exact change that was implemented:

   > Increasing rewards to good questions **may help to make the site more inclusive** by offering a less competitive and speed-oriented way to build one’s reputation.
   >   <sub>Section 6 of May, Wachs, and Hannák, [*Gender differences in participation and reward on Stack Overflow*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10664-019-09685-x), 2019.</sub>

   This seems consistent with the general approach StackExchange has taken towards becoming more welcoming.

It's possible there are also additional (but perhaps less important) motives, one of which is the one described in the question: to give a boost to moderators.

Comment: FYI I deleted my comment since I put it into answer (was on my way to bed and was hoping people would pick up on the stated timeline, but nobody yet..). so you may want to just link directly to that post instead :)

Answer (score 8):

No, that was not the motivation. [Jon Ericson talked about that on English.SE meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13506/10754):

> This change has been in the works since August (according to the date of the initial spec) and we'd been considering it for several months before that.
>
> According to the first version of the communications plan, the change was planned for Oct. 29, but it was delayed until yesterday because of scheduling conflicts and vacations. (As a part of that plan, I notified the moderators of the change a few weeks ago to get their feedback on how to present the change to their communities.) In order to meet our quarterly targets, we needed to complete the project before the upcoming holidays. Since the prep work was ready, the sooner the change was made the better.
>
> The main reason for the change was to correct what we believe was a mistake to change the reputation payout in the first place. That it also makes people feel better is something of a pleasant side-effect. Since people tend to be loss averse, we only considered changes that would let people gain reputation.

I have not seen any mention of "getting more people to help with community moderation activities" as a motivation from any staff, including in private mod area like that feedback post. (I am also not aware of any sites that are hurting for high-enough-rep community members due to the current drama, either - the most urgent community moderation task is flagging spam anyways, which is not a high-rep privilege.)

Comment: "get their feedback on how to present the change to their communities" -> Those that mean that *some* community had some special meta announcement made by their mod (in addition to the blog post everybody had)?

Comment: @BelovedFool Most of the feedback on the Teams post just focused on what to say in the main meta / blog post, but a few sites did post announcements on their local meta: [SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391250/) and [ru.SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9753) for instance, there might be more I didn't see.